# Zend_Form how to put <a> behind input text?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I try to put some HTML link behind input text and I try to do it's somthing like this:

```
$aElements[$iKey] = $oName = new Zend_Form_Element_Text($aValue['newsletter_question_answer_id']);
$oName->addDecorator('HtmlTag', array(
                        'tag' => 'a',
                        'href'=>'http://some_url.html',
                        'placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::APPEND
                    ));
```

and my question is how can I put somthing between `<a>` and `</a>` ?

Best Regards

Comment: Check out the [AnyMarkup decorator](http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/62).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You don't want to write Your own decorator You have to use callback:

```
$element->addDecorator('Callback', array(
    'callback'  => function($content, $element, $options) { 
        Zend_Debug::dump($content, 'content'); //elements decorated so far
        Zend_Debug::dump($element, 'element'); //current element
        Zend_Debug::dump($options, 'options'); //other options

        return "<a href=\"{$options['href']}\">{$options['label']}</a>";
    },
    'option' => 'value', //everything but 'callback' and 'placement' gets 
                         //passed to callback as option
    'href'  => 'http://example.com',
    'label' => 'Link!',
    'placement' => Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract::APPEND
));
```

Ofcourse it's php5.3 style callback, but You can use oldstyle too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask - there's paragraph about accepting answers - please do that :] You and me will get reputation points - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation