# zend_form decorator content

Tags: html, forms, zend-framework, decorator

hey guys I have a problem adding text inside an added html-tag

I have this:

```
public $elementDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'span', 'class' => 'checkbox','description' => 'Club')),

public function init() {
    $this->setMethod('post');
    //$this->setAttrib('action','index');
    $this->addElement('checkbox', 'Club', array(
        'decorators' => $this->elementDecorators,
    ));
//omitted code
```

which outputs:

```
<span class="checkbox" markup="Club" description="Club">
<input type="hidden" name="Club" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="Club" id="Club"  value="1"></span>
```

And what I need to do is have this:

```
<span class="checkbox" markup="Club" description="Club">This is club
<input type="hidden" name="Club" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="Club" id="Club"  value="1"></span>
```

I figure it shouldn't be that hard but I can't figure out an easy/good way to do it.
Any suqqestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately You can't add content to HtmlTag decorator. You need to write Your own, or use callback decorator - check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9812186/1278879